# Laplace analysis of an unstable multivibrator based on an op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, feedback, frequency-domain

I have tried to do a Laplace analysis of the following astable multivibrator circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiecMu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I understand the principle of working. and although the component values were somewhat arbitratry, the circuit oscillates(provided i set the initial charge on the capacitor to some random, small, non-zero value, as is the case with a real circuit).

The next thing I tried to do was to do an analysis in the s-domain. I started with modeling with the following block diagram:

[image]

If we assume an input and set it to zero, I worked out out the total transfer function to be :

$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} \approx \frac{1}{-H_{1}(s) + H_{2}(s)}$$

I have simplified this assuming the open loop gain A is very large.
Now I have tried to plot the closed loop poles and zeros.

What i found is:

$$z = \frac{-1}{R_{1}C} \ \ \ \ ;\ \  p = \frac{R_3}{R_1 R_2 C}$$

both of which are **REAL**.

My quesetion is, how come the circuit is oscillating if the closed loop pole is real? I would expect the result of this analysis to be an exponentially growing signal until it hits the positive rail and settles.

Where did I go wrong or what am I missing? and does this have anything to do with the system having memory? How does that fit into the analysis?

Note this is not a homework or a school assignement, it is my own digging hence I can't seek help from a professor or check the solution somewhere. And upon searching the web I couldn't find someone who has done this type of analysis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is Vin on your diagram? Where is G(s) in your first formula? Your analysis would produce an output that is not restricted to power rails (an important defining feature of this type of oscillator). It's a bang-bang system and, probably can't be analysed using Laplace terms due to extreme non-linearity.

Comment: Vin is assumed to be zero, since we're not inputting anything we only have the output fed back. About G(s), G(s) is simply equal to A, the open loop gain. I mentioned that I simplified the total transfer function from A/(1+AH1+AH2) to the one I posted. if A is very large 1/A can be neglected.

Comment: @Andyaka During a course of communication circuits, we assumed the exponentially growing oscillations to be bound by the power rails. something like if Vo > +Vcc , consider it as Vo = +Vcc

Comment: There are no exponentially growing oscillations in a bang-bang circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka So Laplace analysis isn't suitable for this? what better tool might you suggest ?

Comment: *what better tool might you suggest* -->what are you trying to achieve? There is no indication in your question so, inevitably, I have to ask you this.

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil Look up [*"Modeling and Synchronization of Multivibrator Oscillators"* by Leonardo Acho, 2013](https://portalrecerca.csuc.cat/71589622). It's a short paper, [directly deals with the example you provide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNlgj.png), and may give you a boost in the right direction.

Comment: @Andyaka You're right in that it isn't very evident what the goal is. So what I'm trying to achieve is some sort of mechanical method to approaching these types of circuit configuration.

Comment: @periblepsis Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it right now.

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil Thanks for letting me know. Hope it helps. (It makes use of Laplace, as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you assume an input to the summing junction and the opamp has proper plus and minus operating voltages.

Laplace analysis gave to you a pole which is real and positive. That's a perfect sign of an unstable circuit. It actually means an output which grows with no limit. But soon the output voltage meets the maximum which is set by the operating voltage and the opamp type. Your circuit is no more in the validity range of Laplace domain transfer function analysis. You clash to a wall, no way to continue with Laplace transfer functions. They are valid only to linear circuits. I must add that nonlinear circuits in some cases can be linearized for small signals around an operating point, but this is not such case, because there's no such thing as lasting operating point.

Hopefully you soon understand that this is a Schmitt-trigger which is connected to charge and discharge C1 through R1. The voltage of  C1 swings between the two tresholds caused by the positive feedback. The oscillation period can be found by calculating with normal RC circuit charging equation how long it takes to change the voltage of C1 from the lower treshold to the upper treshold and back (after the Schmitt-trigged has flipped its state).

Comment: I mean, it is correct for small signals -- it's just that those are millivolts if that, for a typical embodiment of this circuit; and the pure RHP pole means the amplitude diverges very quickly, so the transform will only apply for those first, say, microseconds. (Which is already kind of a peculiar thing to say, about an analysis that assumes steady-state conditions!)

Answer (score 1):

The right half plane real pole indicates an unbounded behavior and that’s how far a linear Laplace analysis can go. Or rather, it stops there: that’s the only answer you get from it.

This needs a transient analysis to get the behavior of the system. Now, the transient analysis doesn’t need to imply numerical solutions to differential equations. It can be approximated using large-scale behavior. In this circuit, the interesting things are piecewise exponential curves intersecting the threshold of the op-amp working as an integrator. The large scale nonlinear behavior can be derived on a couple of napkins. No spice needed :)